# Find the indefinite integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$\displaystyle\int{t^2}{{\sqrt[3]{t^3-1}}}\,dt$. Can someone give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Substitution. Let $u=t^3-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute the following

- $u=t^3-1$
- $du=3t^2 \, dt \implies \frac{du}{3}= t^2 \, dt$

So that we may now perform the integration by $u$-substitution.
\begin{align}\int t^2 \sqrt[3]{t^3-1} \, dt &= \int \sqrt[3]{t^3-1} \, \underbrace{t^2 \, dt}_{du/3}\\ &= \int \sqrt[3] u \, \frac{du}{3} \\
&=\frac 13 \int u^{\frac 13} \, du \\
&=\frac 13 \frac 34u^{\frac 43} +C \\
&=\frac 14(t^3-1)^{\frac 43}  +C\end{align}

Comment: I'm a little confused on the $3/4$ part

Comment: Anti-power rule: $$\int y^{\frac 13} \, du= \frac{y^{\frac 13 + 1}}{\frac 13 + 1} + C = \frac{y^{\frac 43}}{\frac 43} + C = \frac 34 u^{\frac 43} + C $$

Answer (score 4):

The usual substitution is $u=t^3-1$. Alternately, let $u^3=t^3-1$. Then $3u^2\,du=3t^2\,dt$, so we want $\int u^3\,du$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=t^3-1\implies du=3t^2dt$. Hence,
$$\dfrac{1}{3}\int \sqrt[3]{t^3-1}(3t^2dt)=\dfrac{1}{3}\int \sqrt[3]{u}du$$
You should be able to do this.